# Not able to install the GUI package(odl-dlux-all) related to OpenDaylight Carbon version

Tags: karaf, sdn, opendaylight

I am not able to install the package odl-dlux-all on the Ubuntu 16.04 machine. Following is the error message

> Error executing command: Can't install feature odl-dlux-all/0.0.0:
>   null

VM : Ubuntu 16.04
Opendaylight version : Carbon

What is the issue?

Should i install gnome-desktop for this?

Answer (score 4):

Prat,

This is what I have found. It looks like you and I were in the same boat. I ran into this issue, also. After additional searching, I found that ODL's website has a guide for the DLUX features.

These are the features I installed and it got me where I needed:

```
odl-dlux-core
odl-dluxapps-nodes
odl-dluxapps-topology
odl-dluxapps-yangui
odl-dluxapps-yangvisualizer
odl-dluxapps-yangman
```

Be sure you enter them as separate commands using the `feature:install` command prior to each of them.

I found the guide on ODL's website **[HERE](http://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-carbon/getting-started-guide/common-features/dlux.html)**.

I hope this helps!! :)

Comment: You can install multiple features in the same command - `feature:install <space-separated features>`

Comment: I would add that ODL has auto-completion enabled, so that way you don't need to necessarily search for the name of all plugins. If you begin typing the name of a plugin after "feature:install", and hit TAB, the available plugins will be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

The way OpenDaylight's DLUX features are structured was changed in Carbon. Application-specific logic was broken out into `odl-dluxapps-*` Karaf features for easier maintenance.

Install and start OpenDaylight:

```
sudo dnf install -y http://cbs.centos.org/repos/nfv7-opendaylight-70-release/x86_64/os/Packages/opendaylight-7.0.0-1.el7.noarch.rpm
sudo systemctl start opendaylight
```

Connect to the Karaf shell (make take a moment for Karaf's SSH server to come up):

```
ssh -p 8101 karaf@localhost
# password: karaf
```

See the available DLUX features:

```
opendaylight-user@root>feature:list | grep dluxapps
odl-dluxapps-yangutils
odl-dluxapps-yangui
odl-dluxapps-topology
odl-dluxapps-yangvisualizer
odl-dluxapps-applications
odl-dluxapps-yangman
odl-dluxapps-nodes
features-dluxapps
```

Install the ones you're interested in:

```
opendaylight-user@root>feature:install odl-dluxapps-topology
```

In a browser on the same machine:

```
http://localhost:8181/index.html#/yangui/index
```

Login with admin/admin and things should work.

[Here are the DLUX docs](http://docs.opendaylight.org/en/latest/getting-started-guide/common-features/dlux.html).

Note that DLUX isn't widely used by ODL developers, and isn't packaged as a product by vendors. Most people use the REST API directly to query OpenDaylight. There are REST API examples in the [NetVirt Postman Collection](https://git.opendaylight.org/gerrit/gitweb?p=netvirt.git;a=tree;f=resources/commons;hb=HEAD), as an example.

Answer (score 1):

It is true. You have to install all dlux features manually.

The Change against ODL Boron is, that Carbon removed feature odl-dlux-all. And in Carbon odl-dlux-core installs only core and nothing more. I had always gray login page in DLUX WEB login, there was nothing, only blank gray page.

I suggest you to use command: feature:list | grep dlux

This will create for you complete list of available DLUX features. And You have to install all of them.

After you finish installation of DLUX use same command with parameter -i which will show you only succesfully installed features:
feature:list -i | grep dlux

so you will see the result.

Don't forget that after instalation Dlux needs a few minutes to be fully ready. If you try to login to dlux during this time, you can get ERROR403 but also login page will not accept the credentials even they are correct. So be patient and wait.

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
   DOCUMENTATION OF OPENDAYLIGHT 
   IS HORIBBLE AND SOMETIMES PURELY WRONG
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+